# Как устранить ошибку: «call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback»?

Tags: php

Выложил сайт на хостинг, затем возникла проблема при регистрации на сайте, после заполнения и нажатия кнопки "регистрация" страница просто обновляется, сообщение о успешной регистрации не выходит, форма сама остаётся заполненной. До этого всё проверял в Denwer, там регистрация проходила успешно.
В журнале на хостинге, показывает такую ошибку при регистрации: **mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'SiteController' does not have a method 'actionIndextsite' in /var/www/vhosts/tddsv.ru/tddsv/components/Router.php on line 81, referer: https://tddsv.ru/user/register/.** Не понимаю от куда взялся этот метод actionIndextsite. По сути должен вызываться actionIndex. Могли вы пожалуйста помочь ?

**Router.php**

```
<?php

/**
 * Класс Router
 * Компонент для работы с маршрутами
 */
class Router
{

    /**
     * Свойство для хранения массива роутов
     * @var array
     */
    private $routes;
  

    /**
     * Конструктор
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        // Путь к файлу с роутами
        $routesPath = ROOT . '/config/routes.php';

        // Получаем роуты из файла
        $this->routes = include($routesPath);
    }

    /**
     * Возвращает строку запроса
     */
    private function getURI()
    {
        if (!empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
            return trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Метод для обработки запроса
     */
    public function run()
    {
        // Получаем строку запроса
        $uri = $this->getURI();

        // Проверяем наличие такого запроса в массиве маршрутов (routes.php)
        foreach ($this->routes as $uriPattern => $path) {

            // Сравниваем $uriPattern и $uri
            if (preg_match("~$uriPattern~", $uri)) {

                // Получаем внутренний путь из внешнего согласно правилу.
                $internalRoute = preg_replace("~$uriPattern~", $path, $uri);

                // Определить контроллер, action, параметры

                $segments = explode('/', $internalRoute);

                $controllerName = array_shift($segments) . 'Controller';
                $controllerName = ucfirst($controllerName);

                $actionName = 'action' . ucfirst(array_shift($segments));

                $parameters = $segments;

                // Подключить файл класса-контроллера
                $controllerFile = ROOT . '/controllers/' .
                        $controllerName . '.php';

                if (file_exists($controllerFile)) {
                    include_once($controllerFile);
                }

                // Создать объект, вызвать метод (т.е. action)
                $controllerObject = new $controllerName;

                /* Вызываем необходимый метод ($actionName) у определенного
                 * класса ($controllerObject) с заданными ($parameters) параметрами
                 */
                $result = call_user_func_array(array($controllerObject, $actionName), $parameters);

                // Если метод контроллера успешно вызван, завершаем работу роутера
                if ($result != null) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**SiteController**

```
<?php

/**
 * Контроллер CartController
 */
class SiteController
{

    /**
     * Action для главной страницы
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        // Список категорий для левого меню
        $categories = Category::getCategoriesList();

        // Список последних товаров
        $latestProducts = Product::getLatestProducts(6);

        // Список товаров для слайдера
        $sliderProducts = Product::getRecommendedProducts();

        // Подключаем вид
        require_once(ROOT . '/views/site/index.php');
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Comment: В смысле откуда он взялся? Вы его туда сами и передаете в значении $actionName, а уж как он туда попал - изучайте, смотрите комментарий от ArchDemon.